# Getter method cannot access its own property

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, getter-setter

I have the following entity Model with property `float $price`.

When I create such a getter method:

```
public function _getPrice()
{
    return $this->price*100;
}
```

It keeps giving me the following error:

> Undefined property: App\Model\Entity\Model::$price

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially trying to access a getter method from within itself.

In order for this to work, try rewriting it as follows:

```
public function _getPrice()
{
    return $this->_properties['price'] * 100;
}
```